# Snakemake creates conda environment but does not activate

Tags: conda, snakemake

I have a Snakefile with a rule to create and activate a conda environment from a yaml file with samtools version 1.9, then to check the version:

```
rule environ:
    conda:
        "envs/samtools.yaml"
    shell:
        'samtools --version > version.txt'
```

And the yaml file:

```
name: samtools
channels:
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - samtools=1.9*
```

I run snakemake using:

```
snakemake --cores 1 --use-conda
```

It seems to build the environment successfully, and when I check the version in .snakemake/conda/79eeda10/bin/samtools it is 1.9:

```
.snakemake/conda/79eeda10/bin/samtools --version
samtools 1.9
Using htslib 1.9
Copyright (C) 2018 Genome Research Ltd.
```

However the output in version.txt indicates the samtools being run is 1.3:

```
samtools 1.3
Using htslib 1.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Genome Research Ltd.
```

When I use this method to run a different rule that needs a specific samtools parameter only available in version 1.9, it also fails due to 1.3 being run instead.

Lastly, I am activating a conda environment containing snakemake before I run this workflow. But I would think there are no issues/conflicts with running a separate environment for specific rules?

Can anyone help me to determine why my conda environment is being built but not activated for these rules?
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

I have realised that samtools 1.3 is the default version on my cluster which is called even when I activate a conda environment with samtools 1.9 installed. To get around this I need to specifically call the samtools binary within my conda path as follows:
/share/ClusterShare/thingamajigs/jamtor/local/lib/miniconda3/envs/py37/envs/snk/bin/samtools

However, this does not solve the problem of building an environment containing samtools 1.9 within a snakemake rule and using this version. Due to the unique hash for the environment build, I would not know the path to specify to call it within the shell command. Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have this issue. Conda prepends to PATH and that should override user- and system-level software. Do you have default `conda init` output in your `.bashrc`? Also, versions of Snakemake and Conda might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem - I had a path pointing to samtools 1.3 in my `PATH` environment variable, in my .bashrc. I removed this and it solved the problem - samtools 1.9 was built and the environment used by snakemake appropriately. Strange as I would have thought the conda environment would take precedence over the `PATH` variable.